# sfRenderException in ubuntu 13.10 and xampp linux 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu, fullcalendar, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony 1.4 application. For development environment I use Windows 7 and Xampp windows 1.8.3. For server I use Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop 32 bit and xampp linux 1.8.3.

All of my application menus are working fine including some javascript auto search fields. I am using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ for a calendar view. I is working fine in my PC but showing the following error in server. I have also gave 777 permission to my entire application to be sure.

500 | Internal Server Error | sfRenderException
The template "CalendarSuccess.php" does not exist or is unreadable in "".

stack trace
at ()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/view/sfView.class.php line 364 ...
      }
      else
      {
        throw new sfRenderException(sprintf('The template "%s" does not exist or is unreadable in "%s".', $this->template, $this->directory));
     }
    }
  }
at sfView->preRenderCheck()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a case-sensitivity issue. Probably your template is named `calendarSuccess.php` or something like that. Windows is case-insensitive when it comes to file names. Linux is not.